# NestJS: How to hide an endpoint in production build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

I want to add an endpoint that would simplify development/testing. At the same time, this endpoint is not needed in production. Coming from Java world, there has always been an out of the box solution (eg with profiles), but I didn't find anything like that in the NestJS documentation.

**Quastion:** Is there a way to implement an endpoint in NestJS that would not be available if the app is built for production use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few options depending on your use-case:

1. Do you have an auth or role based access control scheme? Auth? NestJS has some Auth middleware that might help with this, but might be too heavyweight if this is a one-off: [tutorial](https://dev.to/dannypule/exclude-route-from-nest-js-authgaurd-h0)
2. One fast and loose way to do this would be to return 404 based on an environment variable. Set the env var differently in your dev servers than production.

```
if(process.env.ENV_VAR === 'production') {
  throw new HttpException('Not Found', HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
}
```

3. A good way to do this if you're going to need a lot of internal routes consistently in Prod or out might be to set up private and public routes by essentially adding a second server your project and proxy it differently.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I had similar problem and solved it like this:

```
function getControllers(): Array<Type<unknown>> {
  // add all the non-conditional controllers here
  const controllers: Array<Type<unknown>> = []
  if(process.env["NODE_ENV"] !== "production")
    controllers.push(DevController)
  // possible other conditional controllers
  return controllers
}
```

Now when I create the `AppModule` I do it like this:

```
@Module({
  imports: [/* imports */],
  controllers: getControllers(),
  providers: [/* providers */]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This way I can have conditional controllers that can be included or excluded from the app depending on environmental configuration.